# Prove that $P(X) = P(X|F)P(F) + P(X|\bar{F})P(\bar{F})$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that $F$ and $X$ are events from a common sample space with $P(F) \neq 0$ and $P(X) \neq 0$.

a.) Prove that $P(X) = P(X|F)P(F) + P(X|\bar{F})P(\bar{F})$. Hint: Explain why $P(X|F)P(F) = P(X \cap F)$ is another way of writing the definition of conditional probability, and then use that with the logic from the proof of Theorem

b.) Explain why $P(F|X) = P(X|F)P(F)/P(X)$ is another way of stating Bayes’ Theorem.

Having a bit of trouble with this question. Bayes Theorem hasn't really clicked with me yet. Can someone help me answer this question? And possibly help me better understand Bayes Theorem? I really appreciate all the help.

Edit: I really feel like the more I work on this problem the more I confuse myself I can prove the theory works when I use a made up example of events, but I just can't grasp what I need to do to answer this problem correctly

Comment: it follows from the definition of conditional probability and the law of total probability

Comment: see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further? Sorry im still having issues with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, part (a.) is just the fact that $P(X)$ can be decomposed into two parts: Where $F$ happens and where $F$ doesn't happen.  That is to say $P(X) = P(X\cap F \cup X\cap \overline F) = P(X\cap F)+P(X\cap \overline F)$.  But then $P(X\cap F)=P(F)P(X|F)$ and likewise for $\overline F$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes and $F$ is any event, $P(X) = P(X \cap \Omega) = P(X \cap (F \cup \bar{F})) = P((X \cap F) \cup (X \cap \bar{F}))$.